# CakePHP Ajax Login

Tags: cakephp

Since I'm new to cake, I understand there is a log of magic that happens with a users controller and the `login()` function using `Auth`.

I want to have behavior where I can Ajax post the credentials to users/login, and simply return 1 if it is successful, and 0 if it is not. No redirects, no displays, nothing. I can't seem to make it stop the redirect despite a `$this->render(false)`.

I don't need to make non ajax login requests, so there is no need to test it in the controller.

Could someone suggest what code is needed within the `login()` function in the user controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it redirects because you didn't do an AJAX request (you need to write javascript code for that).

In cake, set $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false in beforeFilter().

> ```
> function login(){
>    if(!empty($this->data)){
>      $this->autoRender = false;
>      if($this->Auth->user())echo '1';
>      else echo '0';
>    }
>  }
> ```